# Camera gets stuck after scanning qr code with zxing

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I implemented QR code scanner with result handler. It is scanning well. But, after first scanning is complete, camera gets stuck. How to implement QR-scanning code so that camera continues scanning without getting stuck?

My code looks like this:

```
public class SimpleScannerFragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {


private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scannerview, null);
    mScannerView = (ZXingScannerView) v.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    mScannerView.startCamera();
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);

}


@Override
public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    ParsedResult parserdResult = ResultParser.parseResult(rawResult);


     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();

   }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code or anything. Nobody can say what you've done wrong just based on this description.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: I used fragment to implement result handler.here i used onPause() and onResume() to start and stop the camera.finally i statically added fragment in activity

Comment: you must post the code of how you handle the result of barcode Result?

Comment: try mScannerView.startCamera(); after you are done with the result in the  handle result

Answer (score 6):

According to manual(https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) just resume your cammera in handler:

```
  @Override
  public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
     ParsedResult parserdResult =   ResultParser.parseResult(rawResult);
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
```

Comment: Even though I call `resumeCameraPreview()` the camera view gets stuck. And even if I call `stopCamera()` nothing happens. Please help

Answer (score 1):

@viper, the best approach which worked for me all the way.

in the onPostExecute

start the camera again and resumecamerapreview.

if you display a dialog in the handleResult or onPostExecute, Dmitri's answer might not work very well.

```
   if (scannerView != null){
        scannerView.startCamera();
        scannerView.setAutoFocus(true); //not necessary
        scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScanActivity.this);
    }
```

this starts the camera and refreshes it

Answer (score 0):

You must resume the camera after pause camera

Test this code

```
public class SimpleScannerFragment extends Fragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

     private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;.

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scannerview, null);
         mScannerView = (ZXingScannerView) v.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
         return v;
     }

     @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         mScannerView.startCamera();
         mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);    
     }


     @Override
     public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
         ParsedResult parserdResult = ResultParser.parseResult(rawResult);
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() + ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onStop() {
         mScannerView.stopCamera();
         super.onStop();    
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resumeCameraPreview(resultHandler: ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler)
startCamera()
```

2 lines of code will make scanner start camera and resume again then continuously scan after scan